# Не отображаются сообщения в ListView(использую FirebaseListAdapter)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, firebase

При вводе сообщения, оно не появляется на ListView(и да, я знаю, что сейчас пользуются RecyclerView).

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


private static final int SIGN_IN_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
private FirebaseListOptions<ChatMessage> options;
private FirebaseListAdapter<ChatMessage> adapter;
Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);

    if(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() == null){
        startActivityForResult(
                AuthUI.getInstance()
                .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                .build(),
                SIGN_IN_REQUEST_CODE

        );
    }else {
        Toast.makeText(this,
                "Welcome " + FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
                        .getCurrentUser()
                        .getDisplayName(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();

        displayChatMessages();
    }

    FloatingActionButton fab =
            (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fab);

    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            EditText input = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.input);

            // Read the input field and push a new instance
            // of ChatMessage to the Firebase database
            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                    .getReference()
                    .push()
                    .setValue(new ChatMessage(input.getText().toString(),
                            FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
                                    .getCurrentUser()
                                    .getDisplayName())
                    );

            // Clear the input
            input.setText("");
        }
    });
}


private void displayChatMessages() {
    ListView listOfMessages = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_of_massages);

    options = new FirebaseListOptions.Builder<ChatMessage>()
            .setQuery(query, ChatMessage.class)
            .setLayout(R.layout.message)
            .build();

    adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<ChatMessage>(options) {
        @Override
        protected void populateView(@NonNull View v, @NonNull ChatMessage model, int position) {
            // Get references to the views of message.xml
            TextView messageText = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.message_text);
            TextView messageUser = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.message_user);
            TextView messageTime = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.message_time);

            // Set their text
            messageText.setText(model.getMessageText());
            messageUser.setText(model.getMessageUser());

            // Format the date before showing it
            messageTime.setText(DateFormat.format("dd-MM-yyyy (HH:mm:ss)",
                    model.getMessageTime()));
        }
    };


    listOfMessages.setAdapter(adapter);
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == SIGN_IN_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Toast.makeText(this,
                    "Successfully signed in. Welcome!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
            displayChatMessages();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this,
                    "We couldn't sign you in. Please try again later.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();

            // Close the app
            finish();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if(item.getItemId() == R.id.menu_sign_out) {
        AuthUI.getInstance().signOut(this)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                "You have been signed out.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();

                        // Close activity
                        finish();
                    }
                });
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

Макет:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ListView class="android.support.v7.app.AlertController$RecycleListView"
    android:id="@+id/list_of_massages"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_above="@id/fab"
    android:dividerHeight="16dp"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"/>

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/fab"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/input"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Input" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_send_black_24dp"
    android:tint="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    app:fabSize="normal"/>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Советую после нажатия fab вызывать

```
adapter.notifydatasetchanged
```